# Getting the number of elements in a generic array

Tags: c#

For a school project, I need to return the number of elements in a generic array (a `T[]` array).

In the constructor I set the array like this:

```
T[] arr = new T[100];
arr.add(3);
arr.add(2);
arr.add(1);
```

To find the size of the array I tried `array.length`, however this return the capacity which would be 100 but it should be 3.

How could I find the correct answer 3?

EDIT:

The `add` function is a simple function that checks if the size is smaller than `default_capacity` add data to array. Size variable is crucial and the function expects the total number of elements in the array.

```
public void Add(T x)
{
    if(size < DEFAULT_CAPACITY)
    {    
       array[size] = x;
    } 
}
```

Comment: `arr.add()` is not a real thing. How are you really setting up the array? Unless you have an extension method you haven't told us about.

Comment: Sounds like you want `List<T>` instead of an array.

Comment: Thanks, however the school gave skeleton code which gave me the `T[]`. So I would assume I need to use that, if I could use list it would be much easier as I could do `arr.Count()`.

Is it possible to check for uninitialise values?

Comment: That *is* an array with 100 elements. Depending on how you're actually populating it in the real code that compiles (if there is any), either 97 or all 100 of them are uninitialized. But the array doesn't keep track of that. It doesn't care. It's not even necessarily a meaningful distinction: In an array of 100 integers, they're all zero by default. If you set `a[14]` to zero, what would you want Count() to return?

Comment: `int count = arr.Count(n => n != default(T));`? Watch what happens if you try adding a `0` value to the array though. EDIT: @EdPlunkett beat me to it.

Comment: @Samuel this seems to be homework, and to your credit you aren't just asking us to do the assignment for you -- but maybe if you explain more what your actual goal is, we could steer you in the right direction

Comment: @EdPlunkett for school I need to create multiple basic data structures one of them is a priorityqueue. To do this school gave me skeleton code (interface) and test so the only thing I needed to do was to implement it, constructor and functions from interface. One of functions is to calculate the size of the priorityqueue another one is the `.add` function and other ones.

Comment: @Samuel You can add your own private field to keep track of the last index where you “added” to the array.

Comment: @itsme86 edited my question to add more explanation about the add function

Comment: Re your edit: that `size` field that you already have is the only way to know what you're asking because that's what's tracking the number of items you've added. That's exactly what `List<T>` does. Using `default(T)` as a marker can give incorrect results because it can be a valid value for certain types.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks your answer to just create a second one was very helpful, and in a later stage I could just create a function that would sort it by priority and put it in the array. Thanks!

Comment: @Samuel Perhaps it may help you to do your work since what you expose looks like that: [List.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the array has not a capacity of 100: it has 100 items.

An array has no capacity, it has `Length` items...

For example, an array of 100 integers has 100 boxes initialized to 0.

And an array has no `add` method...

You may use a `List<T>` instead and you'll have `Count` property and `Add` method.

`List<>` is more smooth and usefull than arrays, but a little less optimized.

If the work is to use a such initialized array, you may use @itsme86 advice in question comment.

But here what is `add` method in your code?

You can use your intended array like that:

```
public class GenericArray<T>
{
  public readonly T[] arr = new T[100];
}

var myArray = new GenericArray<int>();

myArray.arr[0] = 3;
myArray.arr[1] = 2;
myArray.arr[10] = 1;
```

And you still have 100 items: `myArray.arr.Length` is `100`.

You can use a generic list like that:

```
public class GenericList<T>
{
  public readonly List<T> list = new List<T>(100);
}

var myList = new GenericList<int>();

myList.list.Add(3);
myList.list.Add(2);
myList.list.Add(1);
```

And here you have 3 items: `myList.list.Count` is `3`.

The list has here a capacity of 100: it means you can add items without resizing the internal array.

Comment: To use your second option I could have a separate array that is a List and in another function would sort it and put it in the array, thanks!